# How to save PDF file from GoogleDrive to local tmp directory? (c# asp.net mvc)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-drive-api

I'm playing with google drive API and sample DrEdit project, I would like to save picked pdf files into local directory. 
My current steps

1. I'm using DownloadFile method to get file content stream

   ```
   public static string DownloadFile(IAuthenticator auth, String downloadUrl)
   {
       string result = "";
       try
       {
           HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(downloadUrl));
           auth.ApplyAuthenticationToRequest(request);

           HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
           System.IO.Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
           StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
           return reader.ReadToEnd();
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
       }
       return result;
   }
   ```
2. Then I'm converting that to byte[] and try to save:

   ```
   public static string SaveFileToTmpDir(byte[] fileBytes, string fileName)
   {
       fileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("temp"), fileName);
       using (FileStream fs = File.Create(fileName, fileBytes.Length, FileOptions.Asynchronous))
       {
           fs.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
       }           
       return fileName;
   }
   ```
3. Here is my action -> I'm making ajax call from view to that action -> save file in tmp directory and return path to saved file:

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   public JsonResult loadFile(string id)
   {
       IAuthenticator authenticator = Session["authenticator"] as IAuthenticator;
       DriveService service = Session["service"] as DriveService;

       if (authenticator == null || service == null)
       {
           Response.Redirect(Utils.GetAuthorizationUrl("", ""));
       }

       Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File file = service.Files.Get(id).Fetch();
       string fileStream = Utils.DownloadFile(authenticator, file.DownloadUrl);
       string filePath = Utils.SaveFileToTmpDir(StrToByteArray(fileStream), file.Title);
       return Json(new { filePath = filePath });
   }
   ```

but after doing that I'm getting pfd file completly blank. Any ideas to get exact copy?

Comment: can you please show your code where DownloadFile is being called and the result pass to the method SaveFileToTmpDir

Comment: After you call GetResponseStream does your stream variable have a Length property value greater than zero?

Comment: Hi, @Jeff I don't have problems with retriving the bytes - when I save the file it have proper size but evry page insted of contant is blank -> for .txt files I can copy with no problems problems occurs for pdfs, so maybe some additional data are not transmitted (?)

Comment: @krknapik14 did you ever solved this? facing similar problems